# Spring beans not found while loading batch XML configuration, but available in application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Here is my XML configuration file. When I am trying to load it, it is giving an error.But the bean is already present in the application context, which is used to fetch some data and is working perfectly fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd   ">
    <description>Batch Configuration</description>
    <property-placeholder
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        location="./analytics-config.properties" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" />
    <bean
        class="com.intellect.riskanalytics.batch.jobs.instruments.InstrumentsReader"
        id="instrumentReader" scope="step">
        <property name="dataService" ref="dataService" />
        <property name="stepExecution" value="#{stepExecution}" />
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="com.intellect.riskanalytics.batch.jobs.instruments.InstrumentsProcessor"
        id="instrumentProcessor">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataService" />
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="com.intellect.riskanalytics.batch.jobs.instruments.DurationsWriter"
        id="durationsWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="dataService" ref="dataService" />
        <property name="stepExecution" value="#{stepExecution}" />
    </bean>
    <job xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" id="durationsJob">
        <step id="abstractIsinDurationsStep">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk commit-interval="${batch.writer.chunk-size}"
                    processor="instrumentProcessor" reader="instrumentReader"
                    writer="durationsWriter" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>
</beans>


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataService' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 30 more
```

I tried importing it through, ImportResource annotation, CommandlineRunner interface, and a manual call after the server has started. This is the Application class file.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.intellect.riskanalytics.util.Logger;

/**
 * Startup class for launching the application by Spring Boot
 *
 * @see SpringBootApplication
 * @see EnableBatchProcessing
 * @see EnableCaching
 * @since 1.0
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableCaching
@ImportResource("classpath:analytics-batch-test.xml")
public class AnalyticsApplication {
    private static final Logger logger = new Logger(AnalyticsApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    /**
     * Main method to be executed for starting the application in spring context
     *
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments if any
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Starting Risk Analytics Application With Arguments:" + Arrays.toString(args));
        SpringApplication.run(RiskAnalyticsApplication.class, args);
        logger.info("Started Risk Analytics Application");
        createBatchJobsContext("");
    }

    private static void createBatchJobsContext(String batchXMLLocation) {
        batchXMLLocation = "classpath:riskanalytics-batch-test.xml";
        logger.info("Creating Batch XML Application Context with: " + batchXMLLocation);
        // Tried this
        ApplicationContext batchXMLContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { batchXMLLocation },
                applicationContext);
        // And this
        ApplicationContext batchXMLContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(batchXMLLocation);

        logger.info("Created Batch application context: " + batchXMLContext);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by 'your bean is already present'  All I see is an `applicationContext` file that is referring to a bean, which is not defined.  So the error looks legit to me.

Comment: Well, in your configuration file, there are no `dateService` beans nor `jdbcTemplate`. So it looks legit to me that instantiating a bean with a ref to `jdbcTemplate` would throw an error.

Comment: @YassineBadache I think I need to get clarity. Are beans created by spring boot from properties files and auto wired by it are not available while loading the XML configuration?? Because these beans dataService, jdbcTemplate are used long before this file is loaded and there I am not getting any issue.

Comment: Well, considering your case, I would think so. I can't find you the source nor tell you with certainty "this is the case", but I think this is what happens: beans autowired in your code are not available as a reference inside your .xml configuration, especially if you load it manually. Once again, this is no assertion, I'd like someone to confirm and/or prove/disprove the point.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx The bean dataService is autowired while the application is being launched, and I can see it in the list of beans created at localhost:8080/beans. Even if I do this, `<bean id="dataService" class="package.DataService"><constructor-arg index="0" ref="jdbcTemplate" /></bean>`, then it is saying that jdbcTemplate bean is not available

Comment: Okay, I see.  Those beans (should) exist in `applicationContext` and your new one is referring to it.  Try dumping the names of all the beans in that original context, to see if those two are in there with that name.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx Yeah I did that at `localhost:8080/beans`. All beans are available here.

Comment: not sure what `/beans` does, plus that request will be handled _after_ that code was executed.  As a sanity check, dump the bean names in code at that point of execution.

Answer (score 0):

[Joeri Hendrickx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577854/spring-beans-not-found-while-loading-batch-xml-configuration-but-available-in-a#comment88176144_50577854)'s comment gave me a solution. The application context is null in both cases of `ImportResource` and manual loading of XML after the application started. It worked when it is loaded in `CommandLineRunner`'s `run()` method. I think until the completion of `CommandLineRunner` implementations, the application context is not prepared completely.